# "Invalid flag" flag in 10k tools creates potential for flag state superposition

Tags: support, status-completed, flags, 10k-tools, invalid-flags

In the 10k user tools users now have the ability to mark an existing flag against a post as invalid.

When this happens moderators see this as a combined flag that looks kind of like:

```
invalid flag  - [user1] 10 mins ago             [No Action Needed (button)]
too localized - [user2] 30 mins ago
```

Presuming I understand the flagging mechanisms correctly, the problem here is that no matter what action is taken, both users are either given a bump to their flag weight if I dismiss as valid, or both are penalised if the flag is dismissed as unhelpful.

How do I collapse this flag superposition to the correct state?

Comment: Correction:  It looks like a user now has the ability to flag *all* existing flags against a post as invalid (presumably excluding "invalid flag" flags, but who really knows).  I haven't seen a way to mark just one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you mark flags as valid, or invalid they are all actioned in a batch.

"Invalid flags" have special treatment, think of them as users hedging a bet that you will mark the "group" of flags as "invalid"

So, back to your example above. If the post is **not** too localized, mark the "group" invalid. If it is, mark it "valid".

If any flags are marked invalid, **no users receive any flag weight changes for that entire batch of flags regardless of  how they are handled.**

Comment: This needs to be even more like a market: the flag weight you receive for being right should fluctuate as people flag posts a certain way

Comment: need is a strong word, personally I don't really want to complicate things too much ... I am fine for people to game flags a bit, it means they are looking at them ... which is a good thing

Comment: Cheers for clearing that up, I was a bit paralysed with posts that had anti-flags on them, but seems so obvious now. :)