# What's the logic behind suggested edits and flags numbers?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

I just passed the 10k mark on SO and got access to the moderator tools. As a part of that, sometimes a orange number linking to suggested edits shows up. Other times, blue number linking to flagged numbers shows up. Yet other times, both numbers do.

Is there some logic behind them? When do they show up? I couldn't find any. For example, right now, there is almost 100 flagged posts, but the blue number isn't there. Yesterday, there were around 30 and it showed up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flags/notifications in the 10k tools are usually in white text on three different background colors used: Blue, bright orange and brown (sample screenshot below)

[image]

1. The bright orange notification is to alert you of flags are currently in the queue. However, this is only shown when the system considers your current session as being different from your last. For e.g., you come back after a break of a couple of hrs. To dismiss this, simply click on `/tools` and it will disappear and will not reappear until the next unique session.
2. The blue notification (in `tools/flagged`) shows the *current number of flags in the mod queue* that are allowed to be displayed in the 10k tools i.e., flags by Community (vandalism, spam, multiple closed questions) or those by users that don't involve a personal mod message.
3. The dark brown notification to the right of the `tools` link is the *number of pending suggested edits*. This remains even if you visit the tab. However, if you take action on an edit, the number decreases *even if that particular edit requires action from another user*.

Answer (score 3):

The number on a blue background next to the word “flags” is the number of outstanding flags that are shown. For a 10k user who is not a ♦ moderator, these are the [canned flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93623/feedback-on-tools-flagged-changes) on posts such as “does not belong here”, “not an answer”, etc. If you take an action on a flag, or if a moderator dismisses a flag, or if the flag is dismissed automatically (e.g. because the post is deleted). If you wonder what to do with these flags, please read [Which actions using the 10k-moderator-tools do really help the diamond moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96473/which-actions-using-the-10k-moderator-tools-do-really-help-the-diamond-moderators)

[image: 88 flags]

From a `/tools` page, if you click on the `review` tab, you're brought to the `/review` page. When you reach 10k rep, that page receives an additional tab which shows all the pending [suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work). The number on a dark orange background is the number of pending suggested edits.

[image: 22 suggested edits]

The same numbers¹ appear on the top bar in every page: the number of flags on light orange to the left of the `tools` link, and the number of pending edits on dark orange to the right. The flag indicator isn't shown if you've viewed the flag list recently. The number of suggested edits isn't shown if it's less than 5. (This is for Stack Overflow, the rules are slightly different on sites with less volume.)

[image: 119 flags, 44 pending suggested edits]

¹ 
<sub>My screenshots show different numbers because they were taken at different times.</sub>