# Flag flag with incorrect count

Tags: support, flags, 10k-tools, information-display

Very occasionally, on Meta, I'll see a flag count in my header bar, like so:

[image: Why Flag Count?]

I then click on this, and my 10k toolbar will show something like this:

[image: Real Flag Count]

I've actually had this happen quite a few times, and finally remembered to take a snapshot.

My guess is that the number is for flagged comments, but since I'm not a mod I can't see the comments, so there is some glitch showing me the mod flag count.

The tooltip text says

> We have posts flagged for moderator attention, perhaps you can help

Comment: The design has changed since this post has been resolved. However, the same problem persists. See [Review counts in top-bar and /review don't match](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233535/168244).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two possible explanations:

1. The number in the header is the total number of flags in the queue (10k visible + private) and the number in the tab in the `/tools` page is the number of flags that are visible to 10k users.
2. Both of them show only the 10k flag count, but have different cache update times (with the number on the tab being more accurate).

I [used to think](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99956/whats-the-logic-behind-suggested-edits-and-flags-numbers/99958#99958) that it was the former (and still do), but the latter seems like an equally likely possibility.

Comment: I think you're right that it's the first one, since I've never seen seven (and more has been shown) flags in the 10k tools on Meta.