# Review counts in top-bar and /review don't match

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, user-interface, top-bar

So far, I thought that the number shown in the orange box in the top-bar was the number of items available for review. However, when I acually visit `/review`, the numbers don't match:

[image]

Note that top-bar shows 15 items (?) but the queues only add up to 8.

Since I can't think of a reason for this being by design (which, as experience shows, is not a good indicator for "this is not an SE feature) I'm tentatively labelling this a (UI) bug.

Comment: It counts skipped reviews, and it's also slightly cached.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-bydesign]: [“this is everything in review, even stuff that you, personally, can't review. Super-expensive to personalize this - so the alternative is simply not having an indicator”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar/230726#comment758002_230726); plus caching.

Comment: The fix for this "bug" is to hide the distracting/useless orange thingie with a CSS rule, and use some [userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/4086/review-stalker-user-script) instead.

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY: Yea, that's going to be easier on the servers... ;) (Thanks for the link, though.)

Comment: Huh, faulty by design. :(

Comment: That may be easier on the servers, paradoxically. Because few people will install the userscript, and those are exactly the people who do a lot of reviewing. Whereas the alternative is serving custom numbers to *everyone* with review privilege, which for the most part is useless expense: most users don't bother to review.

Comment: On the busy sites it only serves as a one-click access method to Review, since it always has numbers, so the information has no meaning or need.

Answer (score 14):

It won't, at least not always. The review indicator in the top-bar is not calculated on a per-user basis, but on a per-site basis. The counts in the review queue itself *are* calculated on a per-user basis. The top-bar indicator also won't *always* be accurate because it's cached.

There are several things that could cause an item to not show up for you in review, but still show up in the total per-site count. It could be that you've already reviewed the item and it's still waiting to be completed, you could have skipped it, or you could have previously taken action on the post in question that prevents you from being able to review it.

Comment: So, worst-case scenario (which may not be too unlikely on smaller sites) is, user sees "reviews!", clicks, finds nothing to do. Thus we might train them to not click, which is counter-productive. Can we at least only show the bubble if there is *any* work to do? (We can even drop the number if it's meaningless anyway.) I don't see how doing this (even the exact count) is much more expensive than aggregating all the other user-specific data in the top bar.

Comment: Another possibility, depending on how active the site is, that between you seeing the icon and deciding to act on it, other already handled a number of reviews.

Comment: Any plans to fix that?

Comment: it can be fixed.. right?

Comment: @manshu There is nothing to fix, it is working as it is designed to work.

Comment: but it's annoying to find nothing to review when the indicator indicates that "3 total posts awaiting review"