# The maddening brown review number in the navbar displays the wrong number

Tags: discussion, feature-request, navigation

Currently, the review number does not serve to alert me about review tasks I can perform, only that there are review tasks outstanding. I am already aware that this is a known issue, so I am not here to describe it, as that has been

- [done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-many)
- [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239582/review-flag-count-is-still-wrong)
- [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251659/what-does-the-number-next-to-the-review-link-in-the-top-bar-actually-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233535/review-counts-in-top-bar-and-review-dont-match?rq=1),

and I am very open to hearing why my proposal (below) is a bad idea.

The problem with this setup is that I never know when I should click on the reviews to actually perform a task for the community. I would like to formally request that this be changed. The current number of *total reviews in process* should be moved to the **tools** tab, with the other non-actionable data. The navbar is simply too much the nervecenter of the user experience to hold onto non-actionable data.

Making this change would accomplish two things: (a) not driving moderators crazy, and (b) getting items that actually need review to be reviewed much faster. We've already developed a rather Pavlovian response to the navbar - this little tweak could alter the speed of review across the whole site.

Comment: Not a duplicate. This is a formal request to change it.

Comment: There have been countless requests to change it, and it doesn't seem to be high priority, unfortunately. See also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238472/review-count-fix-it-or-lose-it), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237108/can-should-the-review-count-indicator-be-changed-to-be-colour-coded-status-ins?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230833/modulate-the-review-notifications-color-to-reflect-changes-or-make-it-dismissi?rq=1). Hopefully, the new top bar (as used by Stack Overflow) will come eventually, and it'll be gone.

Comment: Worth noting, btw, that the new top bar on SO does not display the number on the bar itself. Although, [there is this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349118/is-the-top-bar-redesign-the-sole-cause-of-the-suggested-edit-slowdown), which may or may not be partially related to said change.