# As 10k+, how does it help that I review flags?

Tags: support, 10k-tools, flags

I've recently passed the 10k limit and gained access to the 10k tools. Reviewing edits certainly helps as well as reviewing posts flagged for closing (where I can directly cast a close vote myself if I think it is correct).

But I don't get the value of reviewing flags, where the only thing I can do is to add my own flag for moderator attention. Before I looked at it the post was flagged, and after I've looked at it and flagged it, it is still just flagged. Does the additional flag from a 10k+ user give any value for the diamond moderators? Or should I rather spend my time on the posts flagged for closing and on reviewing pending edits?

Comment: It will give you flag points if the mods agree.

Comment: @Lance: Yes, it is a very easy way to get more flag weight, just adding my own flag to the obvious cases :-) But does that help the diamond moderators in any way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96473/which-actions-using-the-10k-moderator-tools-do-really-help-the-diamond-moderators

Comment: Why do half of the questions I answer turn out to be duplicates? Probably because half of the questions here are duplicates.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, it does help. Your flag helps move the post up the queue for faster disposal, plus if three or four 10k+ users have flagged for the same reason, we trust your judgement enough to just take a quick glance around instead of five minutes of perusal before deal with it.

Or you can flag as invalid, which lets us know that a case can be made both ways. That helps too. Again, we often rely on the judgement of those nearer to the situation than we are.

**Edit:** Also, 20k+ users can actually vote to delete negatively voted answers, so feel free to downvote any non-answers you may find in the list (both you and the poster can recoup the points once the answer is gone).

Comment: Is 3-4 the most that matters? I occasionally see stuff like "not a real question × 8" or whatever. I've assumed that just means no mods are around at the moment and piling on more flags won't do anything useful.

Comment: @McCannot: Usually four or five is enough to jump to the top of the heap. You have a limited number of flags, so just use your best judgement for allocation.