# Honored "Access to Moderator Tools", and then what?

Tags: support, privileges, 10k-tools

I exceeded 10,000 reps. I have already noticed I can see other people's deleted answers. But who wants to undelete an answer that the answerer him or herself wanted to delete?

Also there is a more easy access to auditing. You are more encouraged by the new blue counter.

My question is, do flag-votes and so on count on my score if I use the "admin" way? Is there any difference? I would guess not, but one cannot ever be sure.

Sorry if this has been answered before, but I couldn't find a similar question.

Comment: As a fellow recent inductee (yesterday?) as well, I too was a tad surprised to see how little utility there was on that mythical page. In addition to deleted answers though, you do also get to see deleted questions, for what that's worth. Well congrats anyway!

Comment: hey @mhlester, I was not disaappointed or surprised at all. My only concern was if there is any difference in doing the tasks as "administrator" regarding flags, closevotes and so on.

Comment: FWIW, quoted to me from @Servy [a few days ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223964/do-moderators-always-have-to-manually-handle-flags-from-the-10k-review-tool/223965#comment730487_223965): I find that almost all of what was once of great value in the 10k tools has since been moved out to /review. I very rarely use them myself precisely because I just don't see value there.

Comment: The "Tools" page is somehow a shortcut, a more easy accessible way. But SO could think of granting this to users really dedicated to auditing without reaching 10k also. If a person makes 2xsteward badges perhaps?

Comment: On second thought... no. Robo-reviewers. Rep is probably a bit more accurate than steward

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, no difference between flagging normally and using the 10k tools. You can cast disagreement flags from the tools though, which is something you can't do from the answer itself.

With the 10k privilege you also get access to [all sorts of awesome statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) (called "tools") and can help [delete closed questions now](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

It's all described on the [10k privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

My favorite feature is being able to edit the tags inline:

[image]

Also, you can't undelete answers until 20k reputation, just see them.

Comment: ! access to all sorts of awesome statistics", so I've heard, but your link does not end to that :)

Comment: Oh, the "stats" tab ...

Comment: @davidkonrad [All of that is stats](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VSyZE.png)

Comment: that page is still ubfuscated for me.

Comment: @davidkonrad What page? I blurred out the screenshot because it was somewhat sensitive data.

Comment: I thank you for the effort and the great detailed answer. There is appearently a lot of things I need to learn regarding the admin tools. You answered my question, there is no difference even if the access to audits is more easy. I will take this in small steps. Regards david