# What actually happens to "Invalid flag" flags?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, 10k-tools

I'm getting mixed messages about what happens when I use an "Invalid flag" flag:

[image: "should be ignored"]

[image: "we'll take a look at it"]

**What actually happens?** I thought I was being helpful by using "invalid flag" to push bad flags down in the queue. Am I actually creating more work for the moderators by raising them in the queue?

Comment: [This comment is false.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox) Actually, it refers to the next comment.

Comment: The previous comment actually refers to this comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96473/which-actions-using-the-10k-moderator-tools-do-really-help-the-diamond-moderator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Thanks, we'll take a look at it!" message is the one that is shown when you use the flagging dialog; the code doesn't check if you selected "invalid flag." I think the message is still valid because moderators still see the flagged post, and decide the action to take. They also see the flag has been marked as invalid from one or more users; in that case, moderators can decline the flag considered invalid without giving a reason for declining it.