# I can dispute flags without 10k rep, and so can you!

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, security, disputed-flags

So I sent this bug report to SE by e-mail, but they told me to post it here...

It [seems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215063/flag-option-in-the-10k-tools-review-should-act-the-same-as-flag-or-disagree/215067#215067) that **anyone can create dispute ("invalid flag") flags on any post**, even if they don't have the 10k "moderator tools" privileges, simply by modifying a normal "flag" link using standard developer tools in their browser.  This is very easy to do:

#### Method A:

1. Right-click the "flag" link.
2. Select "inspect element" from the context menu.
3. Change the class name from "`flag-post-link`" to "`flag-post-link show-invalid`".
4. Click the link normally and select "it has invalid flags" in the popup that appears.

#### Method B:

1. Open the JavaScript console and execute the following statement:

   ```
   $('.flag-post-link').addClass('show-invalid');
   ```
2. Click any "flag" link on the page and select "it has invalid flags".

Turning this into a bookmarklet / user script is left as an exercise.  Or you could modify [this user script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/223701) to work on all pages instead of just the 10k flag review page.

I have successfully used this technique to cast a dispute flag on [a question here on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215063/flag-option-in-the-10k-tools-review-should-act-the-same-as-flag-or-disagree), despite having only 3.5k rep here, and even though the question did not actually have any prior flags to dispute:

> [image: Screenshot]

In principle, this could allow any user to dispute flags on their own posts, if they knew they had been flagged.

While I doubt this would be a very serious issue in practice, and it should be easy enough for mods / staff to detect if it happens, it would still seem a good idea to **add a check to the backend so that such flags would be rejected if the flagging user doesn't have 10k privileges.**

Comment: Plus finding bugs should always be rewarded (especially security based ones), and how can you receive your upvotes by email

Comment: So the `show-invalid` class is only applied if you have >10k rep, then the flagging UI shows that option only if the element has said class? I could be wrong, but the UI should load options based directly on rep, eliminating the "middleman" CSS class.

Comment: By any chance is someone playing with this on this post, I just got an "invalid flag" on this post with no other flags; http://imgur.com/9KkrlaV

Comment: @RichardTingle: Wasn't me.

Comment: Note that you can't actually dismiss flags this way, moderator will still have to manually go over the flags and accept or decline them. However this indeed appears to be a bug, they have to run server side validation when creating that flag.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Presumably you could lower the priority of the flag considerably though such that you "get away with" whatever you're doing for a long time

Comment: @RichardTingle "Not I," said the Trojan. Though I did add the class here, just to see for myself.

Comment: @RichardTingle not sure, it's only one flag and I think it needs 6 to actually remove the flag from the 10K queue. It's all still not 100% clear to me though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard But if **any** user can do this you could sock puppet 6 0 rep users

Comment: @ShadowWizard: AIUI, it could at least be used to [deny any flag weight for the original flagger](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94242). Kind of a petty thing to do, but still, someone _could_ do it. I'm not sure if dispute flags have any effect on, say, the VLQ review queue; if they do, that might be exploitable.

Comment: @RichardTingle [Not quite](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts); it would take a lot more effort than that - 15 rep per sock puppet to flag (unless the flag button can also be added via dev tools). However, your point is valid.

Comment: @RichardTingle no doubt it's a security hole, just saying it's not really that deep of a hole.

Comment: @trojansdestroy: Just injecting a flag link apparently does nothing useful without the JS click handler that makes it work. Didn't feel like diving into the JS code to see if I could reattach it manually. It might be easier to just fake the actual AJAX request, anyway.

Comment: So wait, can you cast.an "invalid flag" flag on a post that isn't even flagged to begin with? Then what would happen?

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow I guess we'll find out from the invalid flags on this post, I guess at some point a moderator will have a confusing day (or perhaps they will never be passed to a moderator and once it reaches 6 invalids it will just be kicked from the 10k queue)

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow: [Apparently](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/693862) it just looks kind of confusing to the mods.

Comment: Though this is definitely a hole, you would have to know that there is a flag to dispute in order for this to be worthwhile...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Fixed in build rev `2014.1.7.1823` on meta and `2014.1.7.1277` on sites.

The POSTed data now gets validated against the list of flag types available to you. Additionally, it's now impossible  to GET the popup GUI with the additional options (by using `show-invalid=true`) if you're not a 10k user.

Comment: I guess all thats left to do now is flag the [invalid flags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged) as invalid and then validity will be restored

Comment: Umm... think you fixed it too well, user with 10048 rep [now don't have that option](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217522/how-to-disagree-with-a-flag). Did you by any chance considered 10K as literally 10K as in 1024*10 = 10240?